# How to separate switch-case block in different PHP tags

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm trying to separate a switch-case code block in different PHP tags like so. but It's returning a Parsing error. Is there a way to separate them code lines like so? :

```
<?php $case = 1 ?>
<?php switch($case) { ?>
    <?php case 1: ?>
    ...
    <?php break; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need an expression inside the parentheses in `switch()`.

Comment: When I change it to `switch(1)` there's no parse error.

Comment: Why you are start and end the php tag in every line. You put complete code in single php tag

Answer (score 0):

After rereading the switch-case documentation you could rewrite the code like so.

```
<?php
    switch(1){
    case 1:
?>
    ...
<?php break;?>
<?php case 2: ?>
   ...
<?php break;?>
<?php } ?>
```

Notice the the first case is inside the same PHP as the switch.